# How can I share the dropdown menu definition accross multiple buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Each line in my table have a dropdown menu that show "Edit, Delete". If i have 100 lines in my table, i have 100 identical dropdown menus definition.

If is possible to **define only one** dropdown menu and use it for all my dropdown buttons? It seems to work but the dropdown menu is not shown at the right place. Is there a way to tell the dropdown menu to change his position to another one?

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#unique-dropdown">Button1</a>
<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#unique-dropdown">Button2</a>

<div class="dropdown" id="unique-dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, you were really close to get what you wanted...

look this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/1jfe3wju/2/

html:

```
<a class="uniquedd" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-info="idofwhatyouwanttoeditordelete" href="#unique-dropdown">Button1</a>
<a class="uniquedd" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-info="otheridofwhatyouwanttoeditordelete" href="#unique-dropdown">Button2</a>

<div class="dropdown" id="unique-dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.uniquedd').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    var p = that.offset();
    actOverWhat = that.data('info');

    //change the actions of the buttons edit and delete

   //check if open
   isOpen = $("#unique-dropdown").hasClass('open');

   if( isOpen ) {
      that.dropdown('toggle');
   }

    $("#unique-dropdown").offset({ top: (p.top + 15), left: p.left });  
});
```

offset is document related, so probably if the page is large won't help, but you have jquery .position();

Comment: interesting but there's a little bug with the way it work. If you click on the first button to open the dropdown and then on button2, it will only close the dropdown. You must press the button2 again to show it. The normal behavior should be that when you click on button2, it close the first one and open the second one.

Comment: the event for opening and closing is managed with data-toggle="dropdown" in anchors... i've updated the code... i'll edit the answer. you still need to do the part that change the behavior of the buttons, so if you click button 1, edit what's attached to button1, and if you click button2 change what  you are editing (or deleting)

Answer (score 0):

You could use less js code. All you need to do is "Append" your class="dropdown-menu" to the class="dropdown" div each time you click an element that should show the menu.

Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/espriella/b4mztvnz/

```
$CHdropdown = $('#ColumnHeaderDropdownId');
$('.sharingdropdown').click(function(e) {
  $(this).append($CHdropdown);
});
```

And this is the HTML sample:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="ChartContentGridId">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div contenteditable style="float:left">Series 1</div>
        <div class="dropdown sharingdropdown" style="float:right">
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div contenteditable style="float:left">Series 2</div>
        <div class="dropdown sharingdropdown" style="float:right">
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th width="20px"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="ColumnHeaderDropdownId">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```