# How to create Multiple Dropdowns into the same dropdown.

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I've been trying to replicate the icons part in the navigation bar on this website https://www.vannuysmaserati.com/

This is what I have so far. I'm not using icons yet. I would like the dropdowns to use one dropdown menu not have one for each. 
https://codepen.io/dmads2355/pen/bQPgbJ

```
<br>
<br>
<div class="container example2">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/candidbusiness/image/upload/v1455406304/dispute-bills-chicago.png" alt="Dispute Bills">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">P <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <p>phone</p>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">H <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <p>Hours</p>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Do you want each parent link to share the same dropdown menu?  Or do you only want one parent link / icon and "P" and "H" item in a dropdown beneath the parent link?

Comment: @Fraze Yes, I want each parent link to share the same dropwdown menu. The same as in the nav bar on this site: https://www.vannuysmaserati.com/

Comment: Seems this may be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059213/how-can-i-share-the-dropdown-menu-definition-accross-multiple-buttons

Comment: @fraze I appreciate you helping me, but thats not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the parent links dropdown menus to drop down in the exact same position. I was thinking I could just manipulate the placement of the dropdown menu class with css so they appear on top of each other.